C# Learing TreeView and a way to display all parents
I'm in the process of playing around with TreeView for the first time, and for now, I have set a goal to be able to display all parents for a given child, as a start.
Goal accomplished on that, but to me it feels like this code could be written better. Any opinions, or if I did something wrong?
//Get selected TreeView item and parents
private void TreeviewMain_SelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem? selectedParent = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    TreeViewItem selectedItem = (TreeViewItem)MainTestList.SelectedItem;
    string parentPath = "";

    if (selectedParent != null)
    {
        parentPath = GetTreeviewParent(selectedParent);

    }

    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        string finalItemPath = parentPath + selectedItem.Header.ToString();
        CurrentItem.Text = finalItemPath;
    }
}

// Form a string of parent names
public string GetTreeviewParent(TreeViewItem item)
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    string parentPath = ">";
    while (!(parent is TreeView))
    {
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            ItemsControl parentItem = parent as ItemsControl;
            TreeViewItem parentName = parentItem as TreeViewItem;
            if (parentName != null)
            {
                parentPath = ">" + parentName.Header.ToString() + parentPath;
            }
        }
    }

    return parentPath;
}


There were a few things I tried while I was figuring out how it works, but this is, by far, the cleanest one... but it still looks like a mess to me at least

How else did you expect to do it? If you wanted it to be more concise you'd use recursion and call GetTreeviewParent from itself. Personally I think the while is a little better as its more readable and there's no chance of a Stackoverflow (when the recursion is too deep). In genreal Treeviews come with slow operations due to the O(log n) nature of their structures. Repeat after me, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

I have refactored your code a little. Logically it is ok, but I have used some C# features, like pattern matching that can make your code bit concise:
//Get selected TreeView item and parents
private void TreeviewMain_SelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parentPath = e.OriginalSource is TreeViewItem selectedParent
        ? GetTreeviewParent(selectedParent)
        : "";

    if (MainTestList.SelectedItem is TreeViewItem selectedItem)
        CurrentItem.Text = parentPath + selectedItem.Header;
}

// Form a string of parent names
public string GetTreeviewParent(TreeViewItem item)
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    string parentPath = ">";
    while (parent != null && parent is not TreeView)
    {
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);

        if (parent == null)
            continue;
        
        if (parent is TreeViewItem parentName)
            parentPath = ">" + parentName.Header + parentPath;
    }

    return parentPath;
}

I also removed couple of .ToString(), as when concatenating, conversion to string is done automatically.
Also improved a little the loop - if you expect parent to be null, you have to account for it and break the loop. If not, you could remove this null check.
